# Share cookies between react-native and swift

Tags: swift, react-native, webview, wkwebview

I am in a bit of a pickle.
I have an app (old, ugly, not mine) that uses react-native (0.29[!])
and swift.

I am letting the user login into a site in the react-native part of the app, later on I want him to continue browse the site as the user he logged in.

Is there a way to let swift to use the same cookies and user data that the webview of react-native has?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you must check the react native cookies , get cookies from there and synch to wkwebview cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiples possibilities to do that:

- You have to create your own native module to pass the cookie thought the bridge. You can get more information [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios)
- You can also use a library to store this sensitive information on the Keychain and get it on the swift side with the keychain too

If you have some code example or more information, I can help you more